# If smaller type value substitute for larger variable, what happen?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int s = (char)1;
    int *p = &s;
    printf("%x", *p);
}

output
1
```

I tried to find out if int type variable is declared and substitute for char type value 1, rest of 3 bytes of variable s is initialized or not. For this output, can I think each of 24 bits of variable s is initialized as 0?

Comment: No, `(char) 1` will get implicitly casted to an int and then be assigned to `s`

Comment: @sshashnak124 Then, char s = (int)0x12345678; This line means what? and I want to find some associated standard or reference. I don't how what keyword I use, can you help me?

Comment: In your other example, `0x12345678` gets truncated into `char` so it's effectively `char s = 0x78`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happen?

The smaller type gets implicitly cast *back* to the larger type, so your explicit type cast does nothing effectively (except that larger values may be truncated).

Functionally, these two lines are identical:

```c
int x = (char) 1;
int y = (int)(char) 1;
```

And these two lines are identical as well:

```c
int x = (char) 257; // Truncated to 1
int y = 1;
```

Comment: `(char)257` is implementation-defined